# Name files for filewriter on mac

Tags: java, macos, filewriter

```
import java.io. * ;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Filewrite1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter ("/Users/StudentFile.txt");
    PrintWriter StudentFile = new PrintWriter (fwriter);

    String name = " ";
    String next = " ";
    int age = 0;
    double gpa = 0.0;
```

I am getting a permission denial on my `/Users/StudentFile.txt`, I am doing this on a mac with netbeans - this is for CSIS 1340 intro to Java.

I think I have a good understanding of the idea - you have to write to and read from files to program - I just don't seem to be understanding my file name? The rest of my program works.

Everyone else is using a pc and they start their file path with `C:`, etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"they start their file path with C:"* - That is because they are using Windows. You are on a Mac... wow, I think you should take an operating systems course, before you begin to program. Also, if that is a mac/-nix path, that looks invalid. It should be similar to *"/home/aaron/path/to/file/StudentFile.txt"*

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied is usual because your user or the user of the JVM doesn't have the right access privileges to the file.
Check the permissions of your file.  you want it to be readable by everybody in this case (I think).

Are you actually trying to write a file to that location?

That location (`Users`) has the permissions `rwxr-xr-x` you can't write to it.

Answer (score 0):

In our application we use express solution for store user's data **independent from any operation systems**. We do this as follows:

```
String slash = File.separator;
String property = System.getProperty( "user.home" );
String fileName ="createdFile.txt";
Writer file = new FileWriter(property+slash+"AppName"+slash+fileName);
file.write(fileReference);
```

**System.getProperty("user.home")** return string with path to UserData folder. And you haven't to hardcode your path.

**File.separator** return correct symbol that help you to build path String